# Using generics in Java to avoid code duplication

Tags: java, generics

I've defined two classes:

```
public class GreffonTramway extends Tramway {

    private ServiceCollecte collecte;

    public GreffonTramway(int nbPlaceAssise, int nbPlaceDebout, ServiceCollecte coll){
         super(nbPlaceAssise, nbPlaceDebout);
         collecte = coll; 
    }

    ...

}

public class GreffonAutobus extends Autobus {

    private ServiceCollecte collecte;

    public GreffonAutobus(int nbPlaceAssise, int nbPlaceDebout, ServiceCollecte coll){
         super(nbPlaceAssise, nbPlaceDebout);
         collecte = coll; 
    }

    ...

}
```

The only difference between them is the name and the class they extend. Would something like this be allowed in Java, so as to have a single file from which we can create both classes?

```
public class Greffon<T> extends <T> {

     ...

     public Greffon<T>(...){}

}
```

If not, how could we achieve this?

Comment: No. C++ does that (curious recursive something?) but not Java. As @Sweeper says, use composition.

Comment: This is not possible. Use composition instead.

Comment: It might be possible to use interfaces and default methods to reduce the duplication, depending on the functionality the classes have