# Is possible extend generic class in java?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I mean

```
public class Generic<T> extends T{
}
```

if I have two classes, in my case it is Response and Request, and several classes with own fields, i want extend response or request depending on the situation or vice versa extend classes. But i do not want to create another classes

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: You can't extend a class without creating another class. So, as it is, your question makes no sense.

Comment: You can do that in C++, but not Java. Use composition. Same as this question from a couple of hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017583/using-generics-in-java-to-avoid-code-duplication#comment104281540_59017583

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible logically per java as by definition of inheritance `you always extend a class not a type`. If you trying to do so, you will see following error:

```
Error:(3, 48) java: unexpected type
  required: class
  found:    type parameter T
```

So, it clear that,

> A class can not inherit from it's type